# Disabling right click , print and view source makes keys P and U not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-click

I disabled right click and print option (ctrl+P ) and view source (ctrl+U)  using javascript. Because of these restrictions keys U and P are not working.Please give me the solution or any alternative way to disable  (ctrl+P  and ctrl+U)option.

And here is my javascript code:
for print

```
if(cc.which == 85)  
{  
return false;  
}  
if(cc.which == 80)  
{  
return false;  
}
```

for right click

```
status="Right Click Disabled";  
function disableclick(event)  
{  
if(event.button==2)  
{  
alert(status);  
return false;    
}  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to disable right click only because you want to disable printing option? If not, then this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006583/capturing-ctrlz-key-combination-in-javascript

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.. I want to disable right click to hide my source code.plz give me solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the user from printing, but you can hide everything when the user prints the document by using simple CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print"> * { display: none; }</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the user from printing, but you can hide everything when the user prints the document by using simple CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    * { display: none; }
</style>
```

refer  : [How to disable printing options in the browser for certain pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359963/how-to-disable-printing-options-in-the-browser-for-certain-pages)

[How to Disable the CTRL+P using javascript or Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843936/how-to-disable-the-ctrlp-using-javascript-or-jquery)