# how to disable Printing of an Xpage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a Xpage that contain some confidential information.Users are supposed to view it but I don't want users to print the content of this Xpage. any Solution ?

Comment: In a browser? It's not possible but you can make it hard for the normal user to print. See for instance this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3359991/785061. But users can always use "print screen" to print the contents

Comment: ... or they might take a picture with their phones ...

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten  many Thanks , it worked for me .